# Firebase emulator does not show url for function in Getting Started

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am following the Firebase [Getting Started tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd). Everything is set up, but when I run

```
firebase emulators:start
```

(stage 7 in the article), where it says

> Check the output of the firebase emulators:start command for the URL of the HTTP function. It will look similar to http://localhost:5001/MY_PROJECT/us-central1/addMessage,

I do not see a url. My output is

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/home/jeff/projects/scratch/fs-test/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: .

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ 127.0.0.1:8080 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

Where is the url?

Do I need other emulators running?

Answer (score 1):

I used firebase-tools version 12.1.0 and it worked fine on my end. I was able to see the deployed function in my local emulator. See logs below:

```
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: helloWorld.
✔  functions[us-central1-helloWorld]: http function initialized 
   (http://127.0.0.1:5001/sample-project/us-central1/helloWorld).
```

In step 4, it says "you can open the source directory and start adding code as described in the following sections". Did you do this?

In your source directory, try to open the index.js file and see if you have written any functions there. In my case, I just uncommented the code snippet below:

```
exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

You can also check the function logs in your emulator UI - http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions

Answer (score 0):

In my index.js I had the same issue! But I figured out the solution.

First I have something like this:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = app;
```

But then I comment the last line:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

// module.exports = app;
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is probably your functions file location.

Note that the emulator tells you:

✔ functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: .

Which means that it actually loads the functions you defined only from the files found in the 'functions' folder in your project, but actually it didn't load any function because no function was defined inside that folder.

Enter to 'Functions' folder, where you will find the Index.js file that include 'Hello World' function in the documentation. Use it and then run the emulator again, then it will show you the URL where you can call the function